# Java SMPP implementation to receive SMS

Tags: java, smpp

What's the best JAVA implementation of SMPP protocol, needed to provide listener on SMSC to receive messages "Reciever accepts Deliver_SM"

With best I mean simple, documentation, Tutorials, Forums..
Appreciate your help 

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

This is a late answer, but for anyone following up might also find the twitter SMPP library to be very helpful. There is great support for windowsize, easy examples to follow and support for high capacity.

https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp/

Answer (score 4):

I did't work on the following but may be helpful for you:

- [JSMPP with Apache Licence](http://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/),
- [Open SMPP by Logica](http://opensmpp.logica.com/introhtml/menu.htm).

Comment: Thanks Ravinder I have already investigated JSMPP but I got shocked with the poor support with no documentation or tutorials :(

Answer (score 2):

I think that jsmpp lib is the best choice because many low level things happen under the hood
and you can focus on the business logic

I used it in many my project and it work well

[JSMPP home page](http://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/)
[SMPP specifications](http://majoron.com/documents/specifications/smpp/SMPP_v5_0.pdf%E2%80%8E)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't :-( Is it possible to delete my post?